# I'm getting (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") but engine is set to innoDb and types are the same

Tags: sql, docker, mariadb, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I basically have 2 simple tables and i reference the primary key of users from the articles table. The engine is set to innoDB and how you can see the data types are int on both ends.

My buddy has the same tables inserted into his database without any errors.
He uses XAMPP and I use Docker if this matters

The errormessage:

ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 25: Can't create table `CMS`.`Article` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    role ENUM("user", "admin") NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Article(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    userId int NOT NULL,
    title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    date date NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

How can i solve this unexpected error?

Answer (score 1):

From ["Identifier Case-sensitivity"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-case-sensitivity/):

> Whether objects are case-sensitive or not is partly determined by the underlying operating system. Unix-based systems are case-sensitive, ... while Mac OS X is usually not, but can be if UFS volumes are used.
>
> ... table ... names are affected by the systems case-sensitivity, while ... column ... names are never case sensitive.

You very likely have the database on a file system, that is case-sensitive. You named the table `USERS` in all caps. That follows, that you have to reference it in all caps from now on.

Try:

```
...
FOREIGN KEY (userid)
            REFERENCES USERS
                       (id)
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=99281e82f3b7cf9a75fd3ed0519ee9ed)

Or change the configuration.

Again from ["Identifier Case-sensitivity"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-case-sensitivity/):

> The [lower_case_table_names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#lower_case_table_names) server system variable plays a key role. It determines whether table names ... are compared in a case-sensitive manner. ... If set to 1 (the default on Windows), names are stored in lowercase and not compared in a case-sensitive manner.

And as a side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL and MariaDB accept that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL or MariaDB versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work i made it so that even if case sensitive no error should come and deactivated Case sensitivity in the settings. Even tried to copy your sql table code from fiddle to my sql file but still doesn't work